# Tool to find out load balance among processors?

Tags: linux, profiling

Is there a tool that will give me information on the load balance of a set of processors? Something like CPU0 23%, CPU1 77%. I need a tool that tells me how balanced is the work my processors have done for a certain multithreaded application (postmortem). This is for Linux, on an Intel CPU, and preferably console-based. Vtune and the such are bloatware, I've found.

Answer (score 0):

These two parallel profilers:

- [TAU](http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/Research/tau/home.php)
- [Scalasca](http://www.scalasca.org/)

permit a console-based analysis of their output and support multi-threading.

The only point I am not sure fits your case is that most of their features need the application to be recompiled and linked against their libraries. Otherwise you will be able to do only a very limited type of analysis and only if the application is dynamically linked.

Answer (score 0):

does nmon suite your needs?

CPU MONITOR SAMPLE OUTPUT

CPU Utilisation -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|---------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+                                    |
|CPU  User%  Sys% Wait% Idle|0          |25         |50          |75       100|                                    |
|  1   0.5   5.0   0.0  94.5|ss >                                             |                                    |
|  2   0.5   0.5   0.0  99.0| >                                               |                                    |
|  3   0.0   0.0   0.0 100.0| >                                               |                                    |
|  4   0.0   0.0   0.0 100.0| >                                               |                                    |
|  5   0.0   0.0   0.0 100.0| >                                               |                                    |
|  6   0.0   0.0   0.0 100.0| >                                               |                                    |
|  7   0.0   0.0   0.0 100.0| >                                               |                                    |
|  8   0.0   0.0   0.0 100.0| >                                               |                                    |
|---------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+                                    |
|Avg   0.1   0.6   0.0  99.3| >                                               |                                    |
|---------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+